# Unable to use #define as a value passed to prototypes, invalid code

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to make use of `#define`'s in a program code, similar to this (simplyfied to the bone) example code:

```
#define M 20
#define N 10

void foo(int *a) {
    if (a == M) { printf("Hello!\n"); }
    else if (a == N) { printf("Goodbye!\n"); }
return;
}
int main(void) {
    foo(M);
    return(0);
}
```

When trying to compile this, I get the following error output:

```
main.cpp||In function ‘void foo(int*)’:|
main.cpp|6|error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|
main.cpp|10|note: in expansion of macro ‘M’|
main.cpp|7|error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|
main.cpp|11|note: in expansion of macro ‘N’|
main.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
main.cpp|15|error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]|
main.cpp|9|error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void foo(int*)’ [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Now, obviously something is wrong here. The purpose of this code is to specify an integer value that can be passed over to the prototype, without having to remember the value of the integer when writing the code. The technique seems to be commonly used in association with sockets, where AF_INET and AF_INET6 represents two different integer values. In that way you don't have to remember the value for the IPv6-protocol if that's the one you would like to us for a socket, you only have to specify AF_INET6.

**Q: How should I write this code to make it work?**

Comment: _Now, obviously something is wrong here._: The error messages do make it _obvious_.

Comment: @devnull Ok, but by specifying &M in stead of M does not solve anything. It only makes things worse...

Comment: Why is `a` even a pointer?

Comment: It'd be better if you mentioned what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Why do you compare pointers to fixed numbers? What do you try to achieve? You are asking for a XY-problem IMHO!

Comment: @devbull - I guess the poster though it was a clue in a cryptic crossword

Comment: Sorry I'm late. Had a run in my tights.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious _'Sorry I'm late'_ Yes, and what?

Comment: It's just so easy to downvote a question and say things are obvious, just because it is obvious to you! That doesn't thereby make it just as obvious to others as well, without having the same knowledge and understanding as you do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foo is accepting a pointer to an Int.  not an int value.  Your define turns into an integer literal.  And will work anywhere an integer literal will work.

You cannot get the address of a literal.

try :

void foo (int a) {

or actually creating a integer variable, and passing the address of it to foo, and dereferencing it in foo back to an int :

```
int main (void)
{

    int myVar = M;
    foo(&myvar)
}

void foo (int *a) {

    if (*a == M) { printf("Hello!\n"); }
    else if (*a == N) { printf("Goodbye!\n"); }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ok, good answer. But in that case:

If the declaration of the prototype had been `void foo(char *a) {}`
then i could have used `foo("Hello!");`, even though "Hello!" isn't a string, but a string value. What's the difference?

Comment: `"Hello"` is internally stored as a `char *` type, hence why `char *str = "Hello";` works. `20` is in int literal, it's not a point, it's a value. It is stored as an `int` value, hence why `int a = 20;` works. C Strings are not values, they're arrays of `char`s, a `char` is a value.

Comment: @SeagulFish, Not as of C++11, as it would need to be `const char *a` due to string literals being `const char[N]`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with any standard.  The very first version of C to present day still treat pointers as a position in memory where the variable is stored, variables are just that values that are subject to change (which are stored in memory at some location), and literals which are "literally" the value, not stored in memory per se, and most likely stored in the code segment as an absolute value or operand to an assembly language instruction.  Its important that you understand this before you start worrying over const-ness or standard specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You do understand that the pre-processor is a very simple creature.

It just replaces any M with 20. I.e. Not a pointer.

So change

```
 void foo(int *a) {
```

to

```
 void foo(int a) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all. You are comparing a  pointer to an integer value whereas what you intent to do is to compare value stored at the location pointed by pointer `a` to `M` or `N`.